# Transitivity of a stochastic order

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be three independent random variables such that $P(X \geq Y) \geq 1/2$, $P(Y \geq Z) \geq 1/2$. Is it true that $P(X \geq Z) \geq 1/2$? It seems true but I'm having a hard time with it and now I started looking for counterexamples.

Also, what happens when $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are not anymore independent? Not a homework question, but I'm just curious, since this seems related with the classical stochastic ordering of random variables (it is easy to check that $P(X \geq Y) \geq 1/2$ is implied by $P(X \geq t) \geq P(Y \geq t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: "it is easy to check that $P(X \geq Y) \geq 1/2$ is implied by $P(X \geq t) \geq P(Y \geq t)$ for all $t$." Hmmm... I would be curious to see a proof of this. (Removed the irrelevant tag (stochastic-analysis).)

Comment: Hmm, sorry, it's actually not that trivial to check, but one can write $P(X \geq Y) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}{F_{Y}(t)dF_{X}(t)} \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{F_{X}(t)dF_{X}(t)} = 1/2$ if I'm not too wrong.

Comment: So you are in fact assuming independence or what?

Comment: yes, assume independence

Comment: But you wrote "what happens when X, Y, Z are not anymore independent?" Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No. A simple counterexample is given by [non-transitive dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice). Taking the first example from Wikipedia, let each random variable select uniformly from a set of three values: $$X \in \{2, 4, 9\},\, Y \in \{1, 6, 8\},\, Z \in \{3, 5, 7\}$$
Then $P(X\ge Y) = P(Y \ge Z) = P(Z \ge X) = \frac59$.

I think these distributions can easily be modified to be interdependent but with the interdependencies so small that the values are each affected by less than $\frac12$, which doesn't alter the winning probabilities at all.